# Mac OS booting till 100 and hanging

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

A week ago my Mac stopped booting. It goes till 99-100% and stops. Booting in safe mode does not help.
I brought my Mac to restore it. They have reinstalled my OS and restored my files. It was working fine at this point.

But, I need all the programs that are there installed and I have restored everything from a backup and got the same problem.

Any ideas what it can cause and what I can do against it?

MacBook Pro late 2013, macOS 10.12.6

[image]

Comment: This is unclear - when they fixed your Mac, ***was it working?***  Then, you restored your files (from Time Machine, I assume) and it stopped?  Also, what Mac model and which macOS?

Comment: Updated the info

Comment: Boot to [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) Hold Cmd-V while turning on and see where it crashes.  Post that info  to your question.  Given that the problem manifests ***after*** you restore your programs, it's a good bet you have something corrupted there.

Comment: I have added the output. After that it prints the Finished polling type 1 (or 4)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect DSMOS is corrupt.

DSMOS stands for ***D***on't **S**teal **M**ac **OS** and is a kernel extension (kext) that's highly encrypted.  If that get's corrupt, there's pretty much no way to recover - you need to do a fresh install.

#### Solution

Do a clean install of Sierra then, using [Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350) move your data and programs over.  It sounds like you are doing a full recovery - don't do this.  Use Migration Assistant.

Comment: Sorry Allan, your solution do not worked. The "do nit steal..." is still in and the System works.
this solutuion worked fine: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7787207?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I don't understand that comment because it 1) contradicts what you described and provided in your original question, and 2) there are multiple "solutions" in the link you just provided; which one are you referring to?